# asp.net url rewriting with IIS integrated pipeline mode

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite

I am new to ASP.NET.  I created a web application and decided to use url rewriting.  I tried several solutions like http://urlrewriting.net and http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/configuration

These solutions worked fine on my localhost.  But when I uploaded it to a shared hosting service provider, all my web pages get 500 internal server errors.

THe web hosting provider told me HttpModules and HttpHandlers are incompatible with IIS Integrated Pipeline mode.  They said  I'm supposed to move my settings into system.webServer...I tried doing that but must have messed up somewhere because I now get 404 errors.   Can someone tell me how to get url rewriting to work for my scenario?  Here's what my original web.config looks like:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet"
             restartOnExternalChanges="true"
             requirePermission ="false"
             type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection,
                  UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"  />
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"></compilation>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule"
type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />

    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <urlrewritingnet
  rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true"
  contextItemsPrefix="QueryString"
  defaultPage = "default.aspx"
  defaultProvider="RegEx"
  xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07" >
    <rewrites>

      <add name="Rewrite"  virtualUrl="^~/([^\/]+)/(\d+)$"
      rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
      destinationUrl="~/$1.aspx?id=$2"
      ignoreCase="true" />
      <add name="Rewrite"  virtualUrl="^~/(search|administrator|Default|logout)$"
      rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
      destinationUrl="~/$1.aspx"
      ignoreCase="true" />

    </rewrites>
  </urlrewritingnet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what they are saying is

1) You have to use the rewriter in .NET
2) You have to set it up to use the URL Rewriter, which sits under system.webServer, not system.web.

If I am correct, they are using the URL Rewriter: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

NOTE: They may not allow your custom HTTP handler (yes, I know it is a published third party, but ISPs are funny like that).